# How to make the hamburger menu appear on all pages in the new blogger theme Emporio

Tags: html, blogger

I know that the only new blogger theme that has the hamburger menu showing on all pages is the Notable one. But I love Emporio. Is there any way to change the HTML to show the hamburger menu on all pages for Emporio, instead of the back arrow button? Thanking you in advance.